# tar suppress message "Treating date ... as ..."

Tags: shell-script, tar

In my script I try to pack the file `test` with:

```
if tar czfv "/tmp/tmp.tar.gz" --mtime="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:00')" "test" --utc;then
```

I get the output

```
tar: Option --mtime: Treating date „2022-10-24 00:00“ as 2022-10-23 22:00:00
```

How do I suppress this output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in the source, GNU `tar` warns you whenever the reformatting of the date [with `tartime()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.c?h=release_1_34#n1083) (so as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS¹) parsed from user input ([with `parse_datetime()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/tree/src/tar.c?h=release_1_34#n1045)) is not byte-to-byte identical to the supplied timestamp, and only when `v`erbose is on.

Here, that is different because the second part is missing (defaulting to 0 in timezones that have an offset to UTC that is an integer number of minutes), and also because with `--utc`, when the current timezone is not bang on UTC.

Assuming you're in a timezone with an offset to UTC that is an integer number of hours, you can make the warning go away if you specify the seconds and run it with `TZ=UTC0`: 0 offset to UTC all year round, so where both input and output date are UTC:

```
TZ=UTC0 tar -czvf /tmp/tmp.tar.gz --mtime="$(
  TZ=UTC0 date +'%F %H:00:00')" test
```

That would also fix the problem whereby the selected time is wrong when run just before the switch to winter time.

To make it work in any timezone, even those such as India's UTC+0530 or Nepal's UTC+0545, or Adelaide's UTC+1030 summer, UTC+0930 winter, you could do:

```
TZ=UTC0 tar -czvf /tmp/tmp.tar.gz --mtime="$(
  TZ=UTC0 date -d "$(date +'%FT%H:00%z')" +'%F %T')" test
```

(not for timezones with non-integer number of minutes offset to UTC, but I don't think there still are nowadays).

You could also filter out the error messages that start with `tar: Option --mtime: Treating date`² portably with:

```
{
  tar... 2>&1 >&3 3>&- |
    grep -v '^Option --mtime: Treating date' >&2 3>&-
} 3>&1
```

But note that it will affect the relative ordering of stdout and stderr messages.

---

<sup>¹ An ambiguous and not post-processable format (even if you use `--full-time`) as it doesn't include the UTC offset.</sup>

<sup>² Beware the message will vary with the locale of the user (`tar: Opción --mtime: Se trata la fecha '2022-10-10 01:30' como 2022-10-10 01:30:01` in Spanish locales, `tar: Option --mtime: Behandle Datum „2022-10-10 01:30“ als 2022-10-10 01:30:01` in German... and may vary between version</sup>

Comment: The first part with the extra seconds is not true! that was my first thought also, but adding the seconds didn't suppress the warning#

Comment: @rubo77, you're right, of course, I was testing it with winter timestamps in mainland Britain timezone, which meant local time was aligned with UTC. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
tar czfv ..... 2> >(grep -v 'tar: Option --mtime')
```

Comment: that works. I added your part before the semicolon: `;then`

Comment: Beware that if done in `bash`, `grep` is not waited for, so you may see its output after `tar` has finished and the script has started running the next commands.

Comment: Note that that sends the other errors on stdout instead of stderr.